# Birational map between singular variety and smooth variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$A$ is singular and $B$ are smooth algebraic varieties.
Is it possible that $A$ is birationally equivalent to $B$?

(over $\mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example: let $A$ be given in the plane by the equation $x^2=y^3$, let $B$ be the affine line $\mathbb C$, and let $f:B\to A$ be the map such that $f(t)=(t^3,t^2)$. You can check that $f$ is birational.

Part of the famous desigularization theorem of Hironaka is that over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero for every varity $X$ there is another $Y$ and a birational map $Y\to X$ such that $Y$ is smooth.

Comment: Nitpick: I guess at the end it is $Y$ who should be smooth.

Comment: That's not a nitpick! :-) Thanks.